# Why does PostgreSQL do Seq Scan when everything is in index instead of index-only-scan?

Tags: postgresql

I am working on this simple example:

```sql
=> create table t1 ( a int, b int, c int );
CREATE TABLE

=> insert into t1 select a, a, a from generate_series(1,100) a;
INSERT 0 100

=> create index i1 on t1(b);
CREATE INDEX

=> vacuum t1;
VACUUM

=> explain analyze select b from t1 where b = 10;
                                         QUERY PLAN
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on t1  (cost=0.00..2.25 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.016..0.035 rows=1 loops=1)
   Filter: (b = 10)
   Rows Removed by Filter: 99
 Planning Time: 0.082 ms
 Execution Time: 0.051 ms
(5 rows)
```

You can see that I select `b` and query on `b` only. And also `vacuum t1;` manually to make sure the Visibility information is stored in the index.

But why does Postgresql still do Seq Scan instead of index-only-scan?

### Edited

After adding more rows, it will do index-only-scan:

```sql
=> insert into t1 select a, a, a from generate_series(1,2000) a;

=> vacuum t1;

=> explain analyze select b from t1 where b = 10;
                                                 QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Index Only Scan using i1 on t1  (cost=0.28..4.45 rows=10 width=4) (actual time=0.038..0.039 rows=1 loops=1)
   Index Cond: (b = 10)
   Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning Time: 0.186 ms
 Execution Time: 0.058 ms
(5 rows)
```

It seems like PostgreSQL doesn't like index-only-scan when the rows number is small.

Comment: Is this something to do with the size of data, that it's easier to page that into memory and scan? I recall reading something about this years ago. Does the query change with 1,000,000 rows and there are more columns than ints

Comment: @MâttFrëëman yeah, you're right. I just updated the question at the same time your comment. It does do index-only-scan after adding more rows. ^_^ Thanks.

Comment: Knowledge is very hazy... But I recall this is something to do with table statistics too (or maybe that was on another rdbms) so query planner needs to have a rough idea of them rather than say doing a count(*) or size(table) internally, perhaps your vacuum triggered the statistics though..

Comment: @MâttFrëëman yeah, thanks a lot for the tip. I have upvoted your first comment. :)

Comment: 100 rows will fit on a single data block, so doing a seq scan will only require a single I/O operation and the index only scan would require the same. Use `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see more details on the blocks (=buffers) needed by the query

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks a lot. I have upvoted it. If you have time, can you provide this as an answer so that I can accept it? Btw, (1) I can not find a good article on `buffers`. So far, I only knew `shared read` means reading from disk and `shared hit` means reading from memory cache. I don't know what the hit num, dirtied etc. are. Does hit=1 means one block?  (2) Before doing `vacuum t1`, not in the question, query was actually doing `Bitmap Heap Scan` followed by `Bitmap Index Scan` instead of `Seq Scan`. I have no ideas why too. If possible, can you explain the above in answer too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody want to provide a detail explanation, I will write a simple answer here.

From @a_horse_with_no_name:

> 100 rows will fit on a single data block, so doing a seq scan will only require a single I/O operation and the index only scan would require the same. Use `explain (analyze, buffers)` to see more details on the blocks (=buffers) needed by the query

From https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/indexes-examine.html:

> It is especially fatal to use very small test data sets. While selecting 1000 out of 100000 rows could be a candidate for an index, selecting 1 out of 100 rows will hardly be, because the 100 rows probably fit within a single disk page, and there is no plan that can beat sequentially fetching 1 disk page.